# SocketServer doesn't work on Linux

Tags: python, linux, python-2.7, sockets

I wrote a simple python script using the SocketServer, it works well on Windows, but when I execute it on a remote Linux machine(Ubuntu), it doesn't work at all..
The script is like below:

```
#-*-coding:utf-8-*- 
import SocketServer

class MyHandler(SocketServer.BaseRequestHandler):

    def handle(self):
        data_rcv = self.request.recv(1024).strip()
        print data_rcv

myServer = SocketServer.ThreadingTCPServer(('127.0.0.1', 7777), MyHandler)   
myServer.serve_forever()
```

I upload it to the remote machine by SSH, and then run the command `python server.py` on the remote machine, and try to access to `xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:7777/test` with my browser, but nothing is printed on the remote machine's teminal...any ideas?

**UPDATE: Problem solved, it's a firewall issue, thanks you all.**

Comment: Are you Sure that Its not a Networking issue ?

Comment: I can access the remote machine with SSH any way ...

Comment: but SSH is on port 22 and you try to access port 7777... Tried connecting from the remote machine, i.e. `telnet 127.0.0.1 7777`?

Comment: Does it work with localhost on the linux machine?  If so and doesn't work remotely, is there a firewall in the way?  I tried this with localhost on a Gentoo linux box and it worked fine.

Comment: @mvds I tried `telnet 127.0.0.1 7777`, it successed ...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are binding the server to `127.0.0.1`, the IP address for localhost. This means the server will only accept connections originating from the same machine; it won't recognize ones coming from another machine.

You need to either bind to your external IP address, or bind to a wildcard address (i.e. don't bind to any particular IP address, just a port). Try:

```
myServer = SocketServer.ThreadingTCPServer(('0.0.0.0', 7777), MyHandler)
```

Comment: I replace 127.0.0.1 to the machine's external IP address, then I can telnet it on the machine itself, but still can't telnet it on my local computer..

Answer (score 2):

You are binding to 127.0.0.1:7777 but then trying to access it through the servers external IP (I'll use your placeholder - xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx). 127.0.0.1:7777 and xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:7777 are *different ports* and can be bound by different processes IIRC.

If that doesn't fix it, check your firewall, many hosts set up firewalls that block everything but the handful you are likely to use

Answer (score 0):

Try with telnet or nc first, telnet to your public ip with your port and see what response you get. Also, why are accessing /test from the browser? I don't see that part in the code. I hope you have taken care of that.

Comment: 'why are accessing /test from the browser?'  Oh, that's just a test..I should see 'GET /test HTTP/1.1 ...' this way..just a personal habbit..

Comment: Wong2: As others have suggested. Don't use 127.x.x.x. Use the External IP and use telnet. Don't go for /test directly. You are SocketServer not the BaseHTTPServer which defines the GET method.

Comment: I replace 127.0.0.1 to the machine's external IP address, then I can telnet it on the machine itself, but still can't telnet it on my local computer..